How to get credentials from SharePoint Online Secure Store?
We need to get credentials from our SPOnline Central Admin Secure Store. Unfortunately the people who were admins left, and there's no documentation around it.
I could only find scripts that work for SP OnPrem.
GitHub has logged that this feature for reading secure store in PnP-Powershell is missing:
https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2180
and it doesn't look like the feature has been added in yet.
Is anyone able to offer any suggestions/solutions?
Thank you

In the case of SharePoint Online (SPO), accessing credentials from the Secure Store Service is not as straightforward as it is for SharePoint On-Premises. There isn't direct support for retrieving credentials from the Secure Store in PnP-PowerShell, as you've noted from the GitHub issue.
What you could try:

Give yourself SharePoint Admin rights (Global Admin can do it)
Reassign Admin Rights in Secure Store (Go to Secure Store >>If you don't see any existing admins, assign new ones)
Reset Secure Store Target Application Credentials

If all else fails and you're completely locked out, consider recreating the target application in Secure Store with new credentials. This is a last resort, as it involves updating all systems dependent on the stored credentials.
